# Trabajar con los resultados obtenidos de una consulta a BBDD desde java

Tags: java

Buenas,

No encuentro la forma de trabajar con los resultados que me devuelve una consulta a Base de datos desde java.

El código donde realizo la consulta es el siguiente:

```
boolean isInsert;
try (PreparedStatement ps = con_actu.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE Codigo_juego = ?")) {
     ps.setString(1, code);
     try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
           isInsert = !rs.next();
     }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo entrar a los datos de los resultados que me de? Necesito comparar si los valores de la base de datos son iguales a los recién sacados, para saber si tengo que actualizarlo y tener un registro de la última vez que se ha actualizado el registro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He modificado tu codigo para que se acerque a lo que deseas hacer , lo dejo a continuacion :

```
boolean isInsert;
try (PreparedStatement ps = con_actu.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE Codigo_juego = ?")) 
{
     ps.setString(1, code);
     try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery())
      { 
            //debes iterar sobre el ResultSet obtenido de la consulta, si el metodo next() retorna true significa que hay datos en la fila siguiente
            while(rs.next())
            {
                //el metodo getXX puede recibir el nombre de la columna o el indice de la columna (estas comienzan a partir del numero 1 )  
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));    
            }

           //isInsert = !rs.next();
     }
}
```

Espero sea de ayuda

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Te dejaré el código de [ejemplo oficial que usa Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html):

```
public static void viewTable(Connection con, String dbName)
    throws SQLException {

    Statement stmt = null;
    String query =
        "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, " +
        "SALES, TOTAL " +
        "from " + dbName + ".COFFEES";

    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
            int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
            float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
            int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
            int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");
            System.out.println(coffeeName + "\t" + supplierID +
                               "\t" + price + "\t" + sales +
                               "\t" + total);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }
}
```

- Cuando la consulta es ejecutada, el resultado se almacena aquí: `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);`
- Empiezas a recorrer el conjunto de resultados: `while (rs.next()) {`
- Obtienes los valores usando el método adecuado y el nombre de la columna. Si es un String y la columna se llama `COF_NAME`: `String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");`
- El resto *habla por sí solo*